# How to execute a url directly after scanning QR Code without showing to the user

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

As the title states, I'm working on a QR scanning function for a cordova application. The code I have currently is able to scan the QR code that I generated, store it into local storage, then display the data stored when another button is pressed. This will cause the URL (.php file stored on localhost) embedded in the QR code to be displayed on the screen, but I will have to tap on it to execute the URL (which will do something to the database).

However, I would like the URL to be executed just after the QR Scanner extracts the URL from the QR Code without showing it to the user. I've looked around online but am unable to find a solution. Would appreciate it if someone could help.

Here is the code for the QR Scanner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>
                    <a target="_blank" href="javascript:scan();" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Scan</button></a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="#display" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Display Scanned Data</button></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="display">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a target="_blank" href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
                <h1>Display</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <table data-role="table" data-mode="column" id="allTable" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            function scan()
            {
                cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                    function (result) {
                        if(!result.cancelled)
                        {
                            if(result.format == "QR_CODE")
                            {
                                navigator.notification.prompt("Please enter name of data",  function(input){
                                    var name = input.input1;
                                    var value = result.text;

                                    var data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
                                    console.log(data);
                                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                                    data[data.length] = [name, value];

                                    localStorage.setItem("LocalData", JSON.stringify(data));

                                    alert("Done");
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                    }
               );
            }

            $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#display", function() {
                $("table#allTable tbody").empty();

                var data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
                console.log(data);
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                var html = "";

                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                {
                    html = html + "<tr><td>" + data[count][0] + "</td><td><a href='javascript:openURL(\"" + data[count][1] + "\")'>" + data[count][1] + "</a></td></tr>";
                }

                $("table#allTable tbody").append(html).closest("table#allTable").table("refresh").trigger("create");

            });

            function openURL(url)
            {
                window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            }

            //initialize
            if(localStorage.getItem("LocalData") == null)
            {
                var data = [];
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                localStorage.setItem("LocalData", data);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does the URL shown? Inside anchor href attribute?

Comment: The scanned URL would be retrieved from localstorage and shown if you press the "display scanned data" button (#display).

Comment: Yes, does it on the `table > tbody` as a list? Inside `<a href="javascript:openUrl('http://blah')">`? Or somewhere else where you want to prevent it to be shown, like on popup?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am also working on the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I used ajax to make a call from the QR scanner code to the php interface on server side, then the callback would echo "success" to the ajax call after the php script has been successfully executed.